# Php date_format localized month names, Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to php and Yii2, and would appreciate any advise.

My website supports 2 languages: English and Mongolian.
I am not sure how to localize month names for Mongolian language, using:

```
date_format(new DateTime($model->start_date), 'd F Y')
```

Is it a proper way to have an array of Mongolian month names, and then create datetime and place a proper name? Or is there any MN libraries to include to standard php localization?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'mn-CN'; //language code like for english --> en-Us
\Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime($model->start_date, 'php:d F Y');
```

or use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: how should I include messages for this locale?

Comment: you need to enable or configure `i18n` component. and it also get messages automatically

Comment: i've already configured file based i18n. How should I add messages for the formatter?

Comment: thank you, but im not sure which encoding to use: `setlocale(LC_TIME, "mongolian"); iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", strftime("%B", strtotime($model->start_date)));` this one doesn't show all the chars.

Comment: to detect char encoding use `mb_detect_encoding($str);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100345/discussion-between-gyuzal-r-and-g4m1tg).